# VBA Comments In a Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, comments

Ive included the whole header of the code just to give some perspective of how many variables I have and how bad i am at this. Currently code works GREAT! Trying to add comments during the copy phase. This code doesn't keep alot of data as it would seriously bog it down. once the reference loops there's no getting it back unless i make a new whole page to dig for it. and Vlookup would go through to many cells to be effective.

This takes a series of events coming due marks the day they are due on calendar with a 1. The calander run 28 days across and then drops down to start the next month(28 days to be exact) i can get comments to work for ANYTHING IN THE first row, but when it attempts to jump down to the second month it errors saying undefined variables. any help would be appreciated.

```
 Sub Planner()
 Dim data As Worksheet
 Dim Cal As Worksheet
 Dim C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9 As Worksheet

 Dim x1C, x2C, x3C, x4C, x5C, x6C, x7C, x8C, x9C As Integer
 Dim y1C, y2C, y3C, y4C, y5C, y6C, y7C, y8C, y9C  As Integer
 Dim Cal1C, Cal2C, Cal3C, Cal4C, Cal5C, Cal6C, Cal7C, Cal8C, Cal9C As Integer
 Dim a1C, a2C, a3C, a4C, a5C, a6C, a7C, a8C, a9C As Integer
 Dim b1C, b2C, b3C, b4C, b5C, b6C, b7C, b8C, b9C As Integer
 Dim c1c, c2c, c3c, c4c, c5c, c6c, c7c, c8c, c9c As Integer


 Dim Com1C, Com2C, Com3C, Com4C, Com5C, Com6C, Com7C, Com8C, Com9C As Integer
 Dim Dest1C As Range
 Dim MDLDate As Integer


 Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
 Set Cal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planner")
 Set C1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C1")
 Set C2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C2")
 Set C3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C3")
 Set C4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C4")
 Set C5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C5")
 Set C6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C6")
 Set C7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C7")
 Set C8 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C8")
 Set C9 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C9")


 Cal1C = C1.Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row

 'sets date MDL was pulled for C2 puts on data page
 data.Cells(1, 7) = C1.Cells(Cal1C, 12).Value - C2.Cells(Cal1C, 13)


 For x1C = 2 To Cal1C 'x = rows y = columns
 For y1C = 50 To 50
    If C1.Cells(x1C, 13) < 1 Then
        data.Cells(18, 8) = "X"
            GoTo next1C
    Else: c1c = C1.Cells(x1C, 13)
        End If

         a1C = Int(c1c / 28) * 24 ' gets the interval of the reference for the column address
         aa1c = a1C + 8 'takes the cell address for column and offsets it to fit cal
         b1C = c1c Mod 28 'get the remainder of the reference for row address
         bb1c = b1C + 3 'takes the cell address for row and offsets it to fit cal
         Set Dest1C = Cal.Cells(aa1c, bb1c) 'tried to set the cell output as a reference but all it equals is 1 not the address. i suspect this is part of my problem. 
         Com1C = C1.Cells(x1C, 8) ' this is text i want in the comment
         Cal.Cells(aa1c, bb1c).Value = 1 ' this is what actually places the number on the calendar based on the cell reference. with the exception of the 1 this is where i want the comments Comm1C.

         With Dest1C
             .AddComment
             .Comment.Text Text:=Com1C
         End With

         Next y1C
 next1C:
     Next x1C
```

Comment: Declarations like this: Dim y1C, y2C, y3C, y4C, y5C, y6C, y7C, y8C, y9C  As Integer    only the last is integer and everything else is implicitly variant. Also, use Long not Integer.  Dim y1C As Long,  y2C As Long etc....

Comment: Which line specifically generates the error message and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Numbered variables like that makes me think that you should be using arrays instead.

Comment: A consolidated set of data like this make me reach for a `Class`.  and `For y1C = 50 To 50` with `y1C` not used in the loop?

Comment: most of the code i learned from Dr. Google or Professor YouTube. I am 100% agreed that this is clunky and not the most streamlined way to do this. BUT HEY! IT WORKS!!! So i'm hesitant and (honestly not smart enough to fix it)

Comment: woops... i think i figured out the issue. it glitches when it hits a cell that requires multiple comments. I need a way to extract the current comments. clear the cell and write a new comment. I think that's the trick.

Comment: when i say glitches i mean returns an error the first time i have multiple cells returning on the same date.

Comment: the reply to QHarr the addcomment line returns the error. put only when it tries to write over a cell multiple times.

Comment: To delete the existing comment and then add a new one?

Comment: Thats the goal... but i dont want to lose whats in there. sometimes multiple events pop up on the same date. I need all those comments. im working on read / copy / clear / add / paste... but im not having any luck. any help would be apreciated.

Comment: You need to focus on using way less variables... there's never a need to make this many declarations

Comment: @dwirony i 100% AGREE. i posted a different post looking for help completing this. but it was way over my head. any suggestions to modify it im open to. i have to have so many unique ones because is used the call function to run multiple macros. i tried 1(1 to 10) but it gave me never ended errros about be undefined because the first macro i use is explicit.

Comment: and to everyone who made a comment about the Dim a,b,c,d not really being declared as an integer i should have listened. just beat my head against a wall for over an hour to remember the multiple comments about this. thanks again! learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for a .Comment first and only .AddComment if one does not already exist. Append the current comment with the new text.

```
     With Dest1C
         If .Comment Is Nothing Then .AddComment
         .Comment.Text Text:=.Comment.Text & Com1C & vbLf
     End With
```

Comment: what is vbLf? the original comment?

Comment: It's a line feed character, aka chr(10). It puts each additional comment on a new line.

Comment: Bro.. if i could send a case of beer through this thing i would! you're my hero! 5 hours of googling and quiet crying and you fixed it in 4 lines of code. I love/ hate this stuff. THANK YOU!